# Setup a Watch Folder over a network

Tags: macos, applescript

I'm trying to setup a Watch Folder in AppleScript which is over a home network. I want the script to generate an email when a file (or files) is dropped in the Watch Folder. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Save a script like this in `~/Library/Workflows/Applications/Folder Actions`:

```
on adding folder items to this_folder after receiving these_items
    tell application "Mail"
        tell (make new outgoing message)
            make new recipient at end of to recipients with properties {address:"name@example.com"}
            set subject to "subject"
            set content to "content"
            send
        end tell
    end tell
end adding folder items to
```

Then enable it from Folder Actions Setup:

[image]

Or if you want to add the files as attachments, add this before the send command:

```
repeat with f in these_items
    make new attachment with properties {file name:f} at after paragraph -1
end repeat
```

Another way to send email is to [use msmtp](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/12387/how-to-send-an-email-from-command-line/40142#40142).